# Discrepancy between Stack Overflow Blog's title and content for author's name

Tags: bug, status-completed, blog, window-title

The author page for [John Au-Yeung](https://stackoverflow.blog/author/john-au-yeung/) [document's title](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/title) is displaying:

> Ryan Donovan, Stack Overflow Blog

There, however, does not seem to exist an author by the name of [Ryan Donovan](https://stackoverflow.blog/author/ryan-donovan/).

[image: Image showing the discrepancy.]

Comment: ALL authors show "Ryan Donovan" in the window title, it's simply hard coded, or taking the first name in the database.

Comment: Not [all](https://stackoverflow.blog/author/yellis/) of them do

Comment: @Yaakov huh! Well, should have guessed! ;)

Comment: No repro @ShadowWizardisEarForYou , must have been a lightning-fast fix. There are a lot of authors with their own name there, although John still has Ryan's.

Comment: @Mast really weird. I checked two more, both showing Ryan: [Mark](https://stackoverflow.blog/author/mark-locklear/) and [Chris](https://stackoverflow.blog/author/chris-sainty/). Maybe it's only for featured blog posts? Didn't bother to check from archive.

Comment: @ShadowWizardisEarForYou I don't believe it's that - unless it's a recent bug. I remember looking at [Jake](https://stackoverflow.blog/author/jgoulding/)'s when it was featured, and it didn't have this bug.

Comment: Hmm... well so can't tell the trigger, but I trust @Yaakov to track this bug down and hunt it down properly. :-)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Thank you for reporting, this one is fixed.

For any interested Wordpress developers, it was a [bad interaction](http://www.prowebguru.com/2017/06/wrong-author-page-title-co-authors-plus/) between two plugins we use - [Co-Authors Plus](https://wordpress.org/plugins/co-authors-plus/) and [Yoast](https://en-gb.wordpress.org/plugins/wordpress-seo/).