# Blog onebox always showing the same author, even when the post is written by someone else

Tags: bug, chat, blog, onebox

For a while now, all the blog posts oneboxed in chat (which is a 50/50 chance, but that's a different issue) appear to be written by Ryan Donovan. However, that's not always true.

The latest case was today:

[image: Chat onebox showing Ryan as the author]

However, as can be seen in the [actual blog post](https://stackoverflow.blog/2022/11/23/why-writing-by-hand-is-still-the-best-way-to-retain-information/), the author is Corissa E Haury:

[image: The actual blog post with a different author]

A couple of more cases from the recent past:

- [November 15<sup>th</sup> onebox](https://chat.meta.stackexchange.com/transcript/89?m=9347647#9347647) showing Ryan as the author, while the real author is Maxwell Wessel. ([blog post link](https://stackoverflow.blog/2022/11/15/speeding-software-innovation-with-low-code-no-code-tools/))
- [November 16<sup>th</sup> onebox](https://chat.meta.stackexchange.com/transcript/89?m=9348860#9348860) showing Ryan as the author, while the real author is Dan Moore. ([blog post link](https://stackoverflow.blog/2022/11/16/biometric-authentication-for-web-devs/))

Can this please be fixed, and onebox made to show the real author?

Comment: Onebox uncovering Ryan's ghostwriting.

Comment: Related: [Discrepancy between Stack Overflow Blog's title and content for author's name](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/344487/241919)